# Resources.load with a scriptable object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, resources

I have a Scriptable Object in Unity that contains a lot a datas (integers and string)

I would like to save data in this scriptable :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4RQZ.jpg

I tried :

```
int cSlot = 0;
StatsPrincess saveP = Resources.Load<StatsPrincess>("ScriptablesObjects/GameSaves/Princess" + cSlot.ToString());

saveP.string1 = mystringtosave1;
saveP.int1 = myinttosave1;
```

This leave "saveP" to "null"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Resources.Load`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html) only works if the asset is somewhere under a folder named "Resources" (and you can have multiple "Resources" folders).

If you want to load with the string `"ScriptablesObjects/GameSaves/Princess"` then the path on the filesystem must be `"Assets/Resources/ScriptablesObjects/GameSaves/Princess"`

Here are the relevant details from the linked documentation:

> Loads an asset stored at path in a folder called Resources.
>
> Returns the asset at path if it can be found otherwise returns null.
>   Only an object of type T will be returned. The path is relative to any
>   folder named Resources inside the Assets folder of your project. More
>   than one Resources folder can be used. For example, a project may have
>   Resources folders called Assets/Resources and Assets/Guns/Resources.
>   String names that include Assets and Resources are not needed. For
>   example the loading of a GameObject at
>   Assets/Guns/Resources/Shotgun.prefab does not use the folder names.
>   Also, if Assets/Resources/Guns/Missiles/PlasmaGun.prefab exists it
>   will be loaded using Prefabs/Missiles/PlasmaGun. If you have multiple
>   Resources folders you cannot duplicate use of an asset name.
>
> Another example of the Resources folder. In Resources there are two
>   files, fancyA and fancyB. Resources also has Resources2 folder. This
>   folder contains two files, fancyA2 and fancyB2. Finally, Resources2
>   has a folder called Resources3 with a single file also called fancyB.
>   (This means the file in Resources3 has the same name as in Resources.)
>   The files in Resources can be loaded as fancyA and fancyB with no need
>   for the folder hierarchy Assets/Resources. Also, the files in
>   Resources2 can be loaded. Loading these require the folder directory
>   so an example load will be Resources2/fancyB2. Finally, loading from
>   Resources3 will be Resources2/Resources3/fancyB.
>
> Note: Extensions must be omitted. Note: All asset names and paths in
>   Unity use forward slashes, paths using backslashes will not work.